# Help to understand this equation $\frac{dw}{d\omega\,d\Omega} = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{|p|^2\sin^2\!\theta\>\omega_0^2}{4\pi c^3\gamma^2}$

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, oscillators, dipole

I'm looking for the name of this equation.

$$\frac{dw}{d\omega\,d\Omega} = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{|p|^2\sin^2\!\theta\>\omega_0^2}{4\pi c^3\gamma^2} \left[\frac{\gamma^2/4}{(\omega-\omega_0)^2 + \gamma^2/4}\right]$$

Comment: is it a capital $dW$ on the L.H.S.?

Comment: Could you add some context in which you encountered the equation? Would be helpful I guess. And p is the dipole moment?

Comment: @CharlesTucker3  Yes. Dipole.I went momentum. Will edit my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at what is there and what isn't there. Where is $\hbar$? Is this a classical process?

$$\frac{dW}{d\omega d\Omega}$$

is usually spectral intensity  (power per hertz per steradian).

$$ \frac 1 {4\pi\epsilon_0} $$

indicates it's an electromagnetic interaction, probably just electric.

The square bracket term is a Lorentzian shape:

$$ \frac 1 {1+x^2} $$

with:

$$ x = \frac{\omega-\omega_0}{\gamma/2} $$

Had the frequencies been squared: $\omega_0\gamma/((\omega^2-\omega_0^2)^2-\omega_0^2\gamma^2)$ you'd think resonant scattering, but this is looking a lot like a spectral line width centered on $\omega_0$, with FWHM $\gamma$. We can include the $(\omega_0/\gamma)^2$ outside the square bracket as part of the energy response...it just sets the amplitude based on the ratio of the peak frequency response to the line width.

The remaining angular part:

$$\frac{|p|^2\sin^2{\theta}}{4\pi c^3} = \frac{p_T^2}{4\pi c^3}$$

peaks at 90 degrees (so the process prefers transverse momentum?). So it's light scattering from something....but what?

Edit: on further review, $p$ is not momentum. It doesn't makes sense as a scattering amplitude....at relativistic  energies you have helicity conservation, and at low energy: spin in not involved. Neither of those give $\sin\theta$.

As a dipole moment it makes much more sense. The electric dipole moment of a charge $q$ at position $\vec d$ is:

$$ \vec p = q\vec d $$

and its dipole field strength goes as:

$$ |p|\sin\theta$$

Which means you formula describes the spectral intensity of the scattering of an incident plane wave:

$$ {\bf E}(x,y,z)= E_0e^{i(kx-t\omega t)}{\bf \hat z} $$

off an atom which has an resonant induced dipole moment, $\vec p(\omega)$ with resonant frequency $\omega_0$ and damping $\gamma$.

It's some combination of Lorentzian oscillators and Hertzian dipoles.